# Sqoop mysql import to HDFS is failed

Tags: sqoop

Here's what I did:

- installed UBUNTU 14.04
- installed HADOOP 2.7.1 version
- installed SQOOP 1.4.6 version
- installed XAMPP 7.0.1 version (for mysql)
- set path in .bashrc for both hadoop and sqoop
- updated the path in sqoop_env.sh file 
  HADOOP_COMMON_HOME and HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME as `/usr/local/hadoop`
- moved the jar file  `/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar`

finally running the below command in sqoop

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/world --username root --table City --m 1
```

And its throwing below error message

> JAVA Exception:
>       Class Not Found Exception: Class City not found

And finally

> Import job failed

Questions:
    Can anyone help me on this issue please? 
    Did i miss any configuration here?

Answer (score 0):

Squoop would generate java code based on the table you specify and would compile for you automatically. It's actually generating java source and compiling in /tmp which would not be in your classpath. If you already have generated jar, you could use `--libjars` to help squoop to find corresponding class file for City table.

Another way to solve your case is, you are missing `bindir` by which you are saying the option argument is where my compiled object should be so it would get picked up by Sqoop. So your command should be:

```
sqoop import --bindir ./ --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/world --username root --table City --m 1
```

Without `--bindir` arguments, Sqoop would place the compiled .class file and .jar file in `/tmp` space. You could refer [here](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.0-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html) for more details.